# Reading XML without schema

Tags: c#, xml

I was using this code to read an xml into a dataset:

```
var ds = new DataSet();
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
     var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);
     sw.Write(reportResults.XmlData);
     sw.Flush();
     ms.Position = 0;
     ds.ReadXml(ms);
}
```

The xml structure was like this:

```
<root>
 <tablename>
   <column1>1</column1>
   <column2>abc</column2>
 </tablename>
 <tablename>
   <column1>2</column1>
   <column2>xyz</column2>
 </tablename>
</root>
```

worked fine. Now xml structure is changing to:

```
<root>
 <tablename>
    <rows>
       <column1>1</column1>
       <column2>abc</column2>
    </rows>
 </tablename>
</root>
```

The same code is producing correct data anymore.

Any idea how to modify the code?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Cannot show much, I am not a c# developer. I tried changing starting position, that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try *InferSchema* parameter.

```
ds.ReadXml(ms, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
```

Comment: No, it does the same thing. ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count = 1, while it should be 104.

Comment: If you are up to it, a simple XSLT can remove `<rows>` tags from the input XML file.